# After enabling Calendar the Next/Prev buttons are off to the side

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I get these two buttons in a better place to make them useful? Currently they reside overlapping the sidebar and calendar almost right in the middle of it. I've looked at documentation and I can't figure it out. I'm using drupal 7. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current dev version appears to have this fixed.

Comment: I tried this and it still did it.  Which version do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using.

version = "7.x-3.x-dev"

core = "7.x"

project = "calendar"

datestamp = "1321704196"

The core version is 7.10.

I did find a way a make the buttons show up in the right place in the recommended release by commenting out the scrollers' "position:absolute" somewhere in the CSS files. I can't remember where exactly it was, but it's quite easy to ferret out with firebug or similar.

You may find this useful:

http://drupal.org/node/1306386